# Manually estimate KS statistic

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I use the proc npar1way with the edf option to produce the KS statistic.

My aim is to use KS to understand if the sample (smp) is different from the population (pop).

When I run the proc npar1way I get the below KS :

```
Kolmogorov-Smirnov Two-Sample Test
(Asymptotic)
KS  0.066667    D   0.133333
KSa 0.516398    Pr > KSa    0.9525
```

My question is: is there any easy way to estimate KS manually in SAS in order to understand better the above outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two sample [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) looks at the largest absolute difference between two empirical distributions $\hat F_1$ and $\hat F_2$

$$
D = \sup_x ~ | \hat F_1(x) - \hat F_2(x) |
$$

so it is fairly easy to calculate it by hand: estimate the empirical cumulative probability distributions, for each $x$ check the absolute difference between the probabilities, keep the largest value. You can find more details about the exact procedure used but the software in the [SAS manual](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/141/npar1way.pdf#section*.37).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!